# Topological connected eccentrics, not homeomorphic to commutative Lie groups

Tags: gn.general-topology, lie-groups, manifolds, universal-algebra, topological-algebras

An eccentric is a universal algebra $\ (X\ \sigma\ \lambda\ \rho)\ $ such that operations
$\ \sigma\ \lambda\ \rho\,:\,X\times X\to X\ $ satisfy:

1. $\quad \forall_{x\ y\,\in X}\quad \lambda(\sigma(x\ y)\ y)\ =\ x; $
2. $\quad \forall_{x\ y\,\in X}\quad \rho\,(x\ \sigma(x\ y))\ =\ y; $

Let $\ \mathcal T\ $ be a topology in $\ X\ $ such that its three operations are continuous.
Furthermore, let topological space $\ \mathbf X:=(X\,\ \mathcal T)\ $ be Hausdorff and connected.

> **Question 1**:   can $\ \mathbf X\ $ be a manifold that is not homeomorphic to any Lie group? Or can $\ \mathbf X\ $ be homeomorphic to a non-commutative Lie group?
>
> **Question 2**:   can $\ \mathbf X\ $ be homeomorphic to Hilbert cube or Knaster pseudo-arc?

## ==========================================

**Examples:**

Topological spaces $\,\ \Bbb R^A\times(\Bbb R/\Bbb Z)^B,\ $ for arbitrary sets $\ A\ B\ $ (possibly empty), are manifolds which admit Abelian group structure; all such Abelian topological groups are topological eccentrics. When $\ A=\emptyset\ $ we get compact manifolds called tori.

## ===================================

**EDIT**

see my EDIT in [Weirdos but algebraic](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/360746/weirdos-but-algebraic).

This thread is ok as it is but in fact, I meant also to have properties:

- $\ \forall_{a\ b\,\in\,X}\quad \sigma(\lambda(b\ a)\ a)\ =\ b;$
- $\ \forall_{a\ b\,\in\,X}\quad \sigma(a\ \rho(a\ b))\ =\ b.$

Comment: Would you help your reader giving examples you have in mind (e.g., those induced by an abelian group structure, as it seems implicit)?

Comment: YCor, done (right?).

Comment: @YCor, thank you for prompting me to supply examples.

Answer (score 1):

These are many questions...

Let me call this E-structure.

The first part of Question 1 has a positive answer. Indeed, the 7-sphere admits a magma structure $(x,y)\mapsto xy$ for which left and right multiplications are invertible with continuous inverse (octonion multiplication). Hence it admits and E-structure with $\lambda(x,y)=xy^{-1}$ and $\rho(x,y)=x^{-1}y$. It's known not to admit any topological group structure however.

[The second part of Question 1 is trivial, since every topological group is an E-structure with these laws. Maybe you mean an W-structure, i.e. the main law satisfying the medial quasigroup property $(xy)(zt)=(xz)(yt)$, as suggested by [your other post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/360746/weirdos-but-algebraic/360824).]

Comment: In general a on a (compact) closed topological manifold $X$ an E-structure is the same as a continuous map $i:X\to\mathrm{Homeo}(X)$ such that for any distinct $x,y\in X$, $i(x)^{-1}i(y)$ has no fixed point. Just the property of admitting uncountably many self-homeomorphism pairwise with no common fixed point is restrictive: among spheres it selects odd-dimensional ones. Among surfaces it only selects the 2-torus and the Klein bottle. So far I'm unable to figure out whether the Klein bottle or the 5-sphere admit such structures, anyway.

Comment: PS in [this paper](https://rj.romai.ro/arhiva/2013/1/Choban,%20Chiriac.pdf) (M. Choban, L. Chiriac, *Selected problems and results of topological algebra*,
Romai J., v.9, no.1(2013), 1–25, ), it is  stated that among spheres, only those of dimension $0,1,3,7$ admit a topological quasigroup structure (that is, a topological E-structure).