# Indecomposable weirdos (cnt.)

Tags: modules, universal-algebra

This post is a continuation of [Weirdos but algebraic](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/360746/weirdos-but-algebraic).

Logically, the quoted post could follow the present one rather than precede it.

**Question** Does there exist an indecomposable weirdo which is neither an Abelian group nor is based on a module over certain left and right rings, with a distinguished invertible element for each of these rings?

These weirdos were described in my previous post. Also, *indecomposable* means indecomposable into a direct (Cartesian) product of two nontrivial weirdos.

## =====================================

**Examples** of indecomposable weirdos:

- every weirdo such that the number of its elements is a prime number is indecomposable;
- every cyclic Abelian group of finite order $\ p^n,\ $ where $\ p\ $ is a prime, is indecomposable;
- the additive Abelian group $\ \Bbb Z\ $ is indecomposable;
- the set of ring $\ X:=\Bbb Z[\frac 12]\ $ is an indecomposable weirdo with respect to:

$$ \forall_{x\ y\in X}\quad \sigma(x\ y)\ :=\ \frac{x+y}2. $$

## ==============================================

**EDIT**

Please. check my "EDIT" from my previous post.

## ==============================================

## ==============================================

**PS.**   Within a day or two, I will leave MO, this time for good.

MO had great potential, I saw it for all these years. It was not fulfilled at all (just the opposite). So be it.

Comment: What about the free one generated weirdo?  Gerhard "It's Weird Enough For Me" Paseman, 2020.05.19.

Comment: A good question!

Comment: Actually an answer to this question was suggested [in my previous answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/360824/14094): take a cancelative magma with the quasimedial property, in which the right multiplications are not all surjective, and modify arbitrary $\lambda$ outside the image of $(x,y)\mapsto (xy,y)$ (and similarly $\mu$ outside the image of $(x,y)\mapsto (x,xy)$). The answer here just plays this game in the case of the additive law on $\mathbf{N}$.

Comment: @YCor, you could write this in an explicit and complete way right here (? I'd welcome it).

Comment: @WlodAA It's even simpler. In both examples you mention (abelian, bimodules+ pair of invertible), the left and right multiplications are bijective (which is automatic for finite E-structures). So any indecomposable W-structure that for which it's not true yields an example. So even the monoid $\mathbf{N}$ works itself.

Comment: Actually, if $X$ is a cancelative magma, and $u,v$ are permutations of $X$, the new magma with law $(x,y)\mapsto u(x)v(y)$ is cancelative as well, defining an E-structure. If $X$ is commutative and $u$ is a single permutation, then $(x,y)\mapsto u(x)u(y)$ defines a W-structure. Even if $X$ is associative, it's not associative in general. So the most obvious examples of W-structures are those for which there is a commutative semigroup $X$ and a permutation $u$ of $X$ such that the law is given by $(x,y)\mapsto u(x)u(y)$. This covers all the given examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if the following example counts as being different
from those listed in the problem, but consider the *weirdo*
with universe $\mathbb N = \{0,1,2,\ldots\}$ and

$\sigma(x,y)=x+y$
$\lambda(x,y)=\rho(y,x) = x\ominus y$, 
where $x\ominus y = x-y$ if $x\geq y$
while $x\ominus y = 0$ if $x<y$.

**Comments.**

Everybody knows that a **quasigroup** is a structure $\langle Q; *, /,\backslash \rangle$
satisfying the laws

(Axioms 1) $(x* y)/y = x$, $x\backslash(x* y) = y$, and 
(Axioms 2) $(x/y)* y = x$, $x*(x\backslash y) = y$.

These say that the operation table of $x* y$ is a Latin square
on $Q$, or equivalently that the maps $x\mapsto a* x$
and $x\mapsto x* b$ are permutations of $Q$ with inverses
$x\mapsto a\backslash x$ and $x\mapsto x/b$.

If we take $\sigma(x,y)=x* y$, $\lambda(x,y) = x/y$,
and $\rho(x,y)=x\backslash y$ and only impose (Axioms 1), then
we get what the OP calls an ``eccentric''.
(Axioms 1) guarantee that multiplication is is cancellative
in each variable, but do not seem to force multiplication
to be a permutation in each variable.

---

The **medial law** for multiplication
is $(x* y)* (u* v) = (x* u)* (y* v)$.

The OP's *weirdos* are medial groupoids satisfying (Axioms 1).
Weirdos satisfying (Axioms 2) are medial quasigroups.

The following theorem from the 1940's is relevant to the question here:

**Theorem.**
(Bruck (1944), Murdoch (1941), Toyoda (1941))

The following are equivalent for a quasigroup $Q$.

(1) $Q$ satisfies the medial law for multiplication.
(2) There is an abelian group structure on $Q$
and two commuting abelian group automorphisms $\alpha, \beta: Q\to Q$
such that $x* y = \alpha(x)+\beta(y) + c$ for some $c\in Q$.

Thus, one does get an affine representation for
*weirdos* satisfying (Axioms 2).

---

If we delete (Axioms 2) we are only guaranteed that
multiplication is cancellative.
But the following is a consequence of Corollary 1.2 of
my paper

A quasi-affine representation.
Internat. J. Algebra Comput. 5 (1995), 673--702.

**Consequence.**
If $\langle Q; * \rangle$ is a medial, cancellative groupoid, then
$Q$ has a quasi-affine representation iff
$Q$ is abelian in the sense of commutator theory.

Thus abelian *weirdos* will have quasi-affine representations.

(Saying that $Q$ has a quasi-affine representation means
that there is an $R$-module $M$ containing
$Q$ as a subset and the multiplication is representable
as $x*y = \alpha(x)+\beta(y) + c$ for some
not-necessarily-invertible
ring elements $\alpha, \beta\in R$ and some $c\in Q$.
You will see from the first example above, involving $\mathbb N$,
why we need to talk about subsets of modules rather than full modules.)

Comment: I suppose it is not known whether there are nonabelian weirdos?

Comment: @მამუკა ჯიბლაძე, In my earlier post I gave an example, in full detail, of a non-abelian weirdo, the one which lives in $\ \Bbb Z[\frac 16].$

Comment: @WlodAA Sorry I should clarify that I mean abelian in the sense of commutator theory, as in this answer. Your example should be such, since it is affine (with $\alpha=2/3$, $\beta=1/3$, $c=0$), no?

Comment: Abelian (in the sense of commutator theory) is not the same as commutative. An algebra $A$ is abelian in the sense of commutator theory if the diagonal of $A\times A$ is a congruence class.

Comment: Keith, thank you for your answer. Also my thanks to @YCor. This is my last OM action (sorry that I don't have the energy to continue or even to complete the present threads. There are also at least equally interesting questions about field-like structures, both algebraic and topological). Good luck.